# How to get previous paragraph text to wrap around an anchored object?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, text-wrap

Here's my problem illustrated with two screenshots.

In the first screenshot the "ideal" scenario, you can see the anchor position (the ¥ between the two paragraphs) of the image, and when positioned to the top corner of the anchor the "wrap text around object" works. The x-offset is just to show that the text does indeed wrap around the image on both sides.

[image]

In this second screenshot the anchor position corner is picked so that the image will protrude into the paragraph that precedes the anchor position, and for some reason the text in that paragraph does not respect the text wrap of the image.

[image]

Why is that and how can I avoid this from happening?

P.S. I wouldn't on purpose choose to place the anchor position this way, but the anchor option "Keep within Top/Bottom column boundaries" is what actually makes this happen even when positioning the image as per screenshot 1, so I'm looking for way to solve this issue of failing to wrap in previous paragraph in a more general sense.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/67194/52050) (this is basically a dupe of the update), and from my answer you can see that is working as intended (although that seems stupid to me) and there unfortunately doesn't seem to be much of an automated workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems to indeed be the same problem as referenced in the answer.